# awk replace value in colunm p row i by value in same column next row

Tags: grep, sed, awk

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
group, , price
1, value, 3.21
1, 3.42, 4.11
1, 3.5, 1.22
2, 4.1, 9.2
2, 4.2, 2.11
EOL
```

I want to replace the value in the 1 row, 2nd column of this file by the value in the 2nd row 2nd column. So I'm looking to have awk return this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
group, value, price
1, value, 3.21
1, 3.42, 4.11
1, 3.5, 1.22
2, 4.1, 9.2
2, 4.2, 2.11
EOL
```

I cannot find how to reference the next line in awk:

```
cat example_file.txt | awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { if (NR==1) $2 = ??}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getline` to get the next line of input, and `split` to split it into an array of fields using the current `FS`:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR==1 && (getline ln) > 0 { split(ln,a); $2 = a[2]} 1' example_file.txt 
group, value, price
1, 3.42, 4.11
1, 3.5, 1.22
2, 4.1, 9.2
2, 4.2, 2.11
```

---

If you want to print the "got" line as well, it's still in `ln` after splitting (to get the order right, we also need to explicitly `print` first, and skip the default print using `next`):

```
$ awk -F, '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS } 
    NR==1 && (getline ln) > 0 { split(ln,a); $2 = a[2]; print; print ln; next} 1
' example_file.txt 
group, value, price
1, value, 3.21
1, 3.42, 4.11
1, 3.5, 1.22
2, 4.1, 9.2
2, 4.2, 2.11
```

Comment: sorry, I meant for the second line to stay as it was (just the value of one particular cell of it being copied one line up). Editing the question now to make this clear

Comment: @user2413 please see amended answer